# Database Last Usage

Tags: sql-server, index, sql-server-2000, monitoring, dmv

Is there a way to find out when a database was last accessed on SQL Server 2000? By this I mean, had a table read, a stored procedure called etc...

I have a list of databases and I am trying to find out which databases are still needed or not.

I'm not sure `sp_who2.LastBatch` will give me the result I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way in SQL 2000 - as it does not support any DMV's introduced in sql server 2005.

Your best bet is to use an [AUDIT trace](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd277388.aspx) or run server side trace.

Note: depending on what you are capturing, it will be resource intensive and might end up filling up your disk space as well.

EDIT:

@rhughes

Refer to this para in the link :

> To achieve a fine-grained approach to these types of auditing, you'll need to turn to **Server-Side Traces**. SQL Server has long provided the ability to trace activity for debugging and performance-monitoring purposes. You can also use Server-Side Traces to monitor security-related activity. Unlike C2 auditing, traces aren't persistent. If you restart SQL Server, the trace is lost and you must recreate it. **Another difference between C2 auditing and traces is that you can start and stop a trace without restarting the database service.** Traces are extremely configurable; you can choose exactly which events to audit and what information about each event to record.

Comment: So if I enable successful and failed login audits, technically I will then have the information to see which databases are being accessed, when and by who?

Comment: @rhughes not **quiet true** as that will tell you who is connecting to your database .. does not necessarily mean they are running SP's or queries ... Read up on server side trace and the events you want to trace, so that you know exactly who is connecting and doing stuff on your server - accessing tables, running SP's, etc.

Comment: OK. I read on that page that you need to restart your SQL server after changing the audit levels. Did I read correctly? Can I setup a trace with no restart (I'm sure I can as I can on 2005+)?

Comment: @rhughes I thing you are confusing 2 different things. If you enable Audit tracing then Yes you have to restart sql server, If you want to start server side trace, you **don't** have to restart sql server.

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully set up a trace on SQL 2000 where I use a job that every hour starts a new trace, then ends the old trace (started by the job that ran an hour ago).  Once the old trace is ended it then processes the data into a summarized table.  Using that methodology I've got traces that tell me when the last time any given object was touched, how many times a given login logged in or out in a given hour etc.

I will say it is somewhat space intensive, and somewhat resource intensive at times, but it does work.

Answer (score 1):

I think I will tell you something that's probably you heard before:
do yourself a favour and upgrade from sql server 2000 to a newer version.

this solution below assumes you did the upgrade:

I found this good script and explanation, plus a detailed addition and pros and cons and [you can find it here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/59440/22336).

I have this query to show me when the database was last accessed.
As per the explanation above it is not perfect.

[Also Be aware](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/169472/22336) [sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/174592/22336) does not return information about memory-optimized indexes. For information about memory-optimized index use, see [sys.dm_db_xtp_index_stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-xtp-index-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

The result of this query should be saved to a table ACCORDINGLY, so that when you restart the server, or the sql server services, you don't lose track of where you are.

```
--==============================================================================
-- The last time a database was accessed
-- marcelo miorelli
-- 30-Apr-2020
--==============================================================================
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
            select @@SERVERNAME AS [Server],
                   sd.[name] AS [Database Name], 
                   sd.create_date as [Created On],
                   last_access_dt = MAX(coalesce(DDIUS.last_user_seek, 
                                                 DDIUS.last_user_scan, 
                                                 DDIUS.last_user_lookup,
                                                 '1/1/1970')),
                   [LAST ACCESS] =CASE WHEN MAX(coalesce(DDIUS.last_user_seek,
                                                         DDIUS.last_user_scan,
                                                         DDIUS.last_user_lookup,
                                                         '1/1/1970')) 
                                            = '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000' 
                                       THEN  'No Access since ' + 
                                             CONVERT (VARCHAR(50), 
                                             (SELECT create_date 
                                                FROM sys.databases 
                                               WHERE database_id = 2),109)
                                       ELSE  'Last Access '     + 
                                             CONVERT (VARCHAR(50),
                                        MAX(coalesce(DDIUS.last_user_seek, 
                                                     DDIUS.last_user_scan, 
                                                   DDIUS.last_user_lookup,
                                                  '1/1/1970')),109)
                                  END,
                   the_time_now = SYSDATETIME(),
                   number_of_days= DATEDIFF(day,MAX(coalesce(DDIUS.last_user_seek,
                                                             DDIUS.last_user_scan,
                                                             DDIUS.last_user_lookup,
                                                             '1/1/1970')),SYSDATETIME())
              from sys.databases SD
   LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats DDIUS 
                ON DDIUS.database_id = SD.database_id

             WHERE SD.database_id > 4 
               AND SD.database_id <> 32767

          GROUP BY sd.[name],sd.create_date
          ORDER BY 4 DESC
```

See the last access takes into consideration the last time the sql server service started.

example of the outcome:

[image]