# Using sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats for unhelpful or unused indexes

Tags: sql-server, index, index-tuning

I'm trying to discover indexes which may be in place which are only adding cost with no value to our database.  I've come across [sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-index-usage-stats-transact-sql) and from [MSSQL Tips](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1239/how-to-get-index-usage-information-in-sql-server/) the following:

> **sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats**
>
> This view gives you information about
>   overall access methods to your indexes.  There are several columns
>   that are returned from this DMV, but here are some helpful columns
>   about index usage:
>
> - user_seeks - number of index seeks
> - user_scans- number of index scans
> - user_lookups - number of index lookups
> - user_updates - number of insert, update or delete operations

Does that mean if there is an index with very few / no seeks+scans+lookups but many updates, then the index is only costing us (have to update index when table is updated) but not gaining us anything?

Second question - Is the following query a decent way to discover this information?

```
SELECT DB_NAME([database_id]),
       OBJECT_NAME(dm_db_index_usage_stats.[object_id], [database_id]),
       TotalReads = (user_seeks + user_scans + user_lookups),
       Writes = user_updates,
       indexes.[name],
       *
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
LEFT JOIN sys.indexes on dm_db_index_usage_stats.[object_id] = indexes.[object_id] and dm_db_index_usage_stats.[index_id] = indexes.[index_id]
ORDER BY (user_seeks + user_scans + user_lookups) ASC, user_updates DESC;
```

Comment: You need to be a bit careful around the timing of your query - the DMV will be reset whenever SQL is restarted so it doesn't necessarily reflect overall usage. If SQL has been restarted recently you could be seeing a partial picture.

Comment: Version will matter here, too. In some versions of SQL Server, rebuilding indexes will reset these metrics. See here for more information: https://littlekendra.com/2016/05/18/index-usage-stats-bug-fixed-in-sql-server-2012-sp2-cu12-sp3-cu3/

Answer (score 4):

Just throwing this out there, because I remember the bad old days of having a different script for every index ailment you read about on the internet.

I co-author a free stored procedure called [sp_BlitzIndex](http://firstresponderkit.org) that will tell you about a whole bunch of stuff going on with your indexes all at once.

Some examples:

- Aggressively locked indexes
- Duplicates (based on keys)
- Borderline duplicates (based on first key column)
- Unused (with differentiation based on number of writes
- High value missing indexes
- HEAPs
- And more!

The simplest example run is probably like this. Just change the database name.

```
EXEC sp_BlitzIndex @DatabaseName = 'StackOverflow', @Mode = 4
```

There are a ton more ways to run it, just check out the docs at the GitHub link.

Hope this helps!